# Application insights page view loss

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm using application insights javascript sdk in a website by snippet. I found that if I open the website and then close the page very quickly, the page view events were loss. But if I use other telemetry capture sdk, the events can be captured. I have already set the "maxBatchInterval" as 0 and the sampling related configuration is by default.
Is there any way to avoid data loss in this situation for application insights?

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens because of SDK doesn't load or initialize. Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript?tabs=snippet#report-script-load-failures) for more information.

> any way to avoid data loss in this situation for application insights?

Yes, we can get all the telemetry data without loss.

I hope you are using the updated latest version of SDK V2.

You can use **autoTrackPageVisitTime** has **true** configuration to view the page view time of the current page.

After, you can measure the duration of the page so that it will send the duration information to the Application Insights using **trackpageView**.

```cs
appInsights.trackPageView({ name: 'pageview with duration = 00:00:30.000', properties: { duration: 500000 } });
```

Comment: I have set autoTrackPageVisitTime true, but I cannot get your point. How can we get the data without page view loss by tracking visit time? I

Comment: you can use the duration property to check the page visit time. Refer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/issues/835#issuecomment-483866223)

Comment: I don't care about the visit time. I just want to reduce the loss of PageView events.